# How to overcome ANRs issue even though i run the background task in GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines, android-threading

The app is prompted with an "App is not responding" window.

In my main activity, inside the button click, I am calling "Background task" Meanwhile I am shown a progress bar in the UI. In the background task, we are using 3 global scope launchers as follows

1. GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { } -- listing the Bluetooth devices.
2. GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {} -- connect with a Bluetooth device
3. GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {} -- attaching the lane connectivity with the device.

Whenever I called the background task, after some time, the App threw an issue "The demo is not responding".

So, I have tried the following methods to fix this issue.

1. Thread -- called the background task and inside the runOnUIThread -- I update the result.-- The Issue I faced with this method is that runOnUIThread is not hit, and the app keeps on showing the progress bar.
2. GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) -- I called the background task inside the suspend function and withContext - updated the UI. -- again withContext did not hit so the progress bar showing infinitely
3. async and wait - I used this method after some time the app is thrown the "app is not responding error" along with the below issue.

   ```
   2024-01-27 14:02:58.008 19304-19320 ResourcesManager        pid-19304   E  failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~FHujqjwch4vKn4hpsBy2QQ==/com.demo.app-PuNlHBKrmNBo9OS13OQ5GA==/base.apk'
   java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~FHujqjwch4vKn4hpsBy2QQ==/com.demo.app-PuNlHBKrmNBo9OS13OQ5GA==/base.apk
       at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
       at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:296)
       at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:145)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:534)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:503)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:190)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:610)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:866)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:936)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1401)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1592)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1509)
       at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1497)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2752)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2240)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2223)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2565)
       at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:242)
       at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadSafeLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:276)
       at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:213)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2610)
       at com.android.server.am.AppNotRespondingDialog.<init>(AppNotRespondingDialog.java:84)
       at com.android.server.am.ErrorDialogController.showAnrDialogs(ErrorDialogController.java:194)
       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleShowAnrUi(AppErrors.java:1247)
       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1922)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
       at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
       at com.android.server.UiThread.run(UiThread.java:52)
   ```

In the button click, I am calling the long-running task as follows,

```
     GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        
            val task = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                status =  backGroundCall()
            }
            task.await()
            runOnUiThread {
                activityBinding.pairLogs.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                activityBinding.pairLogs.text = status.toString()
                activityBinding.demostatus.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                activityBinding.buttnRow.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                activityBinding.progressBlock.visibility = View.GONE
            }
     }
```

and the background call as follows,

```
 private fun backGroundCall(): String{
    status = Demo().testBackGround();
    return status
}
```

Please suggest a way to fix this ANR issue and how to fetch the result from the background task.

Comment: Why are you using GlobalScope instead of a CoroutineScope? Please also share the code associated with the logic you detailed.

Comment: @tomerpacific, I have modified with the background call. Could you please give me more details regarding coroutineScope

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) might help.